# How to remove duplicate values from different rows per unique identifier?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I'm just starting to use R. I have a dataset with in the first column unique identifiers (1958 patients) and **in columns 2-35 0's en 1's**.

For example:

```
Patient A:  0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 NA NA
```

I want to change this to:

```
Patient A: 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tapply` and grouping our variable based on whether it changes value or not, i.e.

```
tapply(x[!is.na(x)], cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x[!is.na(x)]) != 0)), FUN = unique)

#1 2 3 4 5 6 
#0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, it is not clear whether NA's can also occur in the middle, and how you would want to deal with that situation (e.g. make `1 NA 1` to `1 1` (option 1) and hence combine the two 1's, or whether NA would mark a boundary and you would keep both 1's (option 2).
That determines at which point to remove NA's in the code.

You could use `S4Vectors` run length encoding, which would allow you to have more than just 0 and 1.

```r
library(S4Vectors)

## create example data
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(c(0,1), (1958*34), replace=TRUE, prob=c(.4, .6))
x[sample(length(x), 200)] <- NA
x <- matrix(x, nrow=1958, ncol=34)
df <- data.frame(patient.id = paste0("P", seq_len(1958)), x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## define function to remove NA values
# option 1
fun.NA.boundary <- function(x) {
    a <- runValue(Rle(x))
    a[!is.na(a)]
}
# option 2
fun.NA.remove <- function(x) runValue(Rle(x[!is.na(x)]))

## calculate results
# option 1
reslist <- apply(x[,-1], 1, function(y) fun.NA.boundary(y))

# option 2
reslist <- apply(x[,-1], 1, function(y) fun.NA.remove(y))

names(reslist) <- df$patient.id
head(reslist)
#> $P1
#>  [1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
#> 
#> $P2
#>  [1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
#> 
#> $P3
#>  [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
#> 
#> $P4
#>  [1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
#> 
#> $P5
#>  [1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
#> 
#> $P6
#>  [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```